# Pandas. Importar todas las columnas de una hoja Excel en Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

En un libro abierto en Jupyter Notebook, intento importar todas las columnas de una hoja Excel (16), utilizando el script

```
file = "datos.xlsx"
# Import the data
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname = "Financiera", na_values = "n/a")
```

El script funciona correctamente en otras shell's de Python. En Jupyter Notebook, de las 16 columnas, solamente me importa las 9 primeras. ¿Cuál puede ser la causa?.

Con df.column y df. shape obtengo

```
    Index(['TipInv', 'Fondo', 'FechaInv', 'NumPar', 'ValPar', 'ImpInv'], dtype='object')
(23, 6)
```

Modifico el script, de acuerdo con sugerencias de la consulta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163830/ipython-notebook-pandas-max-allowable-columns

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
file = "mis_inversiones.xlsx"
# Import the data
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname = "Financiera", na_values = "n/a")
# Display the head of the data
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
display(df.head())
```

La visualización del df mejora notablemente, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.
Compruebo con una sentencia que utiliza alguna de las columnas desaparecidas para realizar un cálculo, y efectivamente entiendo que el error que muestra indica que no existe dicha columna

```
KeyError: 'Tot_Pond'
```

El libro Excel utilizado en Jupyter, es una copia del utilizado en las shell's en las que el script funciona correctamente.
De las columnas visualizadas, la última contiene datos cálculados en la Excel mediante una fórmula.
De las columnas que hasta este momento no se importan en Jupyter, una son fechas y las otras contienen datos calculados mediante fórmulas.
La versión de Pandas comprobada en Jupyter y en una Shell es la 0.20.3
En la hoja del Libro Excel no existen celdas vacias ni con N/A'.
He vuelto a instalar xlrd. **La versión de xlrd es la 1.1.0**

La opción de importar de .csv (me da el mismo problema), no me sirve, dado que al grabar como .csv, desaparecen las fórmulas y tendría que trabajar con tres hojas Excel, una con cada hoja del libro Excel.

Comment: Mírate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163830/ipython-notebook-pandas-max-allowable-columns, no creo que el problema esté en la carga del DataFrame, puedes ver las columnas cargadas con `df.columns` y las dimensiones con `df.shape` para confirmar si se ha cargado correctamente.

Comment: Con df.shape y con df.columns obtengo  (23, 6)
Index(['TipInv', 'Fondo', 'FechaInv', 'NumPar', 'ValPar', 'ImpInv'], dtype='object')

Comment: Parece que haya algún problema en la excel. Las columnas que no te carga ¿son distintas de algún modo de las demás? ¿Puedes detectar algún patrón? Prueba si no a guardar como .csv y leer este desde pandas.

Comment: Quizás relacionado con [esta issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/99) en la que algunas columnas no se cargan si tienen muchos valores vacíos antes del primer dato. ¿Tienes las últimas versiones de `pandas` y  `xlrd`?

Comment: Es extraño, por tu última edición efectivamente parece un error en la lectura del archivo por parte de Pandas. Por ir acotando un poco y en relación con lo que comenta abulafia ¿Usas la misma versión de Pandas  y xlrd (o cualquier otro engine si lo usaras) cuando usas jupyter y cuando ejecutas el código en la terminal (dónde funciona)?¿En ambos casos el archivo excel y su contenido es exactamente el mismo?

Comment: @efueyo Para ver la versión de un módulo, en la mayoría de los casos lo siguiente funciona: impórtalo en un intérprete (`import modulo`) e imprime `modulo.__version__` o `modulo.__VERSION__`.

Comment: @efueyo Una cosa más. El archivo excel fue generado desde Microsoft Excel? En caso contrario, prueba a abrirlo en Microsoft Excel y guardarlo de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con la libreria pandas

```
import pandas as pd
FileNAME="datos.xlsx"
DAT= pd.ExcelFile(FileNAME)
# Te muestra cuantas hojas tiene el libro de excel
DAT.sheet_names
# En este caso extraeremos los datos de la hoja 1
df = DAT.parse("HOJA-1")
# visualizamos las primeras 5 filas 
df[0:5]
```

Tambien puedes utilizar

```
FileNAME="datos.xlsx"
DATx= pd.ExcelFile(FileNAME,header=1)
DATx.sheet_names
DATx = DATx.parse("DATA-1")
DATx.head()
```

Un saludo, espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: He probado la opción de Ulises y obtengo el mismo resultado. Con df.shape y con df.columns obtengo  (23, 6)
Index(['TipInv', 'Fondo', 'FechaInv', 'NumPar', 'ValPar', 'ImpInv'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

Después de instalar xlrd versión 1.1.0, el script ya funciona correctamente en Jupyter. Queda como sigue:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 21 16:05:50 2017
@author: efueyo
"""
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
file = "datos.xlsx"
# Import the data
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname = "Financiera", na_values = "n/a")
# Display the head of the data
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
display(df.head())
# Inspect the data
df.info()
df.columns
print (df.head())
```

Otro cambio que ha podido influir ha sido rellenar tres celdas vacias identificadas en una de las columnas.